# Probability that a sum of uniformly distributed random variables is large

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, probability-distributions, volume

**Problem**

Let $\ell_1 \le \ell_2 \le \dots \ell_n$ be nonnegative real numbers, and $S$ a nonnegative real number that is smaller than the sum of the $\ell_i$.

Suppose that for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$, a number $a_i$ is picked from the interval $[0, \ell_i]$ uniformly at random.

What is the probability that $$a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n \ge S\text{ ?}$$

**Progress**

If $S > \ell_2 + \ell_3 + \dots + \ell_n$, it seems that the answer is just $$\frac{\left(\ell_1 + \ell_2 + \dots + \ell_n - S \right)^n}{n!\cdot \ell_1\ell_2\cdots \ell_n}.$$
I got this by computing the volume of the associated region, which in this case forms a simplex.

I'm not sure what the answer is in the general case however. If there isn't a nice closed form, I'd still like to find an algorithmic approach that could determine the answer quickly.

Comment: I gather this is a practical problem, since you say you'd be interested in an algorithmic approach.  How large is $n$ liable to be in practice?

Comment: In practice $n < 100$, and usually around $50$.

Comment: Mike Earnest's great answer will be computationally impractical then.  Too bad.

Comment: True. The result presented there is really pretty though. And, if I mainly cared about computational results, then probably the easiest approach would just be to use Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little easier to think about $\mathbb P( a_1+\dots+a_n\le S)$, then subtract from $1$.

It turns out that

> $$P( a_1+\dots +a_n\le S)=\frac{1}{n!\ell_1\cdots \ell_n}\sum_{I\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}}(-1)^{|I|}\Big(\Big(S-\sum_{i\in I}\ell_i\Big)^+\Big)^n,$$
>   where the notation $x^+$ means $\max(x,0)$.

Essentially, the argument is inclusion exclusion. We start by considering the volume of the simplex defined by $\{a_i\ge 0,\sum_i a_i\le S\}$. This is $S^n/n!$.

However, this simplex might extend outside of the box. For each $j$, the simplex defined by $S_j=\{a_i\ge 0 \forall i,a_j\ge \ell_j ,\sum_i a_i\le S\}$ will be a part of the first simplex extending outside the box, which is nonempty $S\ge \ell_j$. The volume of this simplex is the same as that of $S_j'=\{a_i\ge 0 \forall i ,\sum_i a_i\le S-\ell_j\}$, which is $(S-\ell_j)^n/n!$.

However, for any $j,k$, the two simplexes $S_j$ and $S_k$ we subtracted might actually overlap. Their overlap is the volume of $S_{j,k}=\{a_i\ge 0\forall i,a_j\ge \ell_j,a_k\ge \ell_k,\sum_i a_i\le S\}$. This overlap is nonempty whenever $S\ge \ell_j+\ell_k$, and the volume is $(S-\ell_j-\ell_k)^n/n!$. This volume must be *added* back in, since is was subtracted out twice when subtracting the singly overflow simplexes in the last paragraph.

Continuing in this fashion, you get the displayed formula. The $(\cdot)^+$ notation takes care of all the casework automatically.

There is probability a simpler way to derive this by finding the characteristic function of $a_1+\dots+a_n$ and using the inversion formula, but I haven't quite been able to get that to work out.